# How to use LDAP user registries with custom form login page in Websphere Liberty 8.5?

Tags: ldap, websphere, web.xml, websphere-liberty, server.xml

I have defined [LDAP user registry](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ldap.html) and made a [custom form login page](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_config_custom_user_login_form.html) in my Dynamic Web Application which running at [Websphere Liberty Profile 8.5.5](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/as_ditamaps/was855_welcome_liberty_core.html)

How can I bind my form from login page to LDAP user registry, so all user's credentials will be checked against this LDAP registry?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1) One way is to define mapping in `server.xml` - see [Setting up BasicRegistry and role mapping on the Liberty profile](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_sec_basicreg_full.html), although it says about Basic registry, defining mapping is the same:

```
<application type="war" id="myWebApp" name="myWebApp"
             location="${server.config.dir}/apps/myWebApp.war">
   <application-bnd>
       <security-role name="user">
           <user name="Bob" />
           <user name="user1" />
           <group name="mygroup" />
       </security-role>
   </application-bnd>
</application>
```

2) If you don't want to change `server.xml` you can define these mappings in the application in the binding file - `ibm-application-bnd.xml` -  like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application-bnd
    xmlns="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee http://websphere.ibm.com/xml/ns/javaee/ibm-application-bnd_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">

    <security-role name="user">
        <user name="user1" />
        <group name="mygroup" />
    </security-role>
</application-bnd>
```

If you are packaging app in the EAR, put that file in the META-INF folder.

If you are deploying war, create META-INF folder and put it there (this is currently undocumented feature, but is working at least in 8.5.5.6).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the information to configure LDAP registry

https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ldap.html

In addition to that, you may also need to set the realm-name in your form-login declaration.  For example,

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>MyRegistryRealmName</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
      <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
      <form-error-page>/error.jsp</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```